# How can I structure git like this on my local machine?

Tags: git

I have this folder stricture for a project I'm working on:

```
.
├── dist/
├── environments/
├── index.html
├── lib/
├── node_modules/
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

Now, I want only the CONTENTS of `dist` folder to be on the `master` branch(not the `dist` folder itself) and none of the other files and folders outside the `dist` folder.

However, all of the top level files and folders, including `dist` have to be commited to the `dev` branch.  How can I structure GIT like this?

Comment: Why would you want it like this?

Comment: Building a blog using jekyll and github pages. On my master branch I only want the static content obtained after running `jekyll build` to be there, and raw structure will be on the dev branch

Comment: The above structure is a sample btw, not the actual one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a clean way to do what you're exactly asking. It would require a lot of manual branch switching that is unusual and grains against Git operations.

If you just want to separate your true "source" files from the "built", It is common to have a `build` directory which you can place in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I ended up moving the `dist` folder outside the src folder, and then putting both folder into different branches

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd better have a publish script that push your `dist` folder in the `gh-pages` branch.

Like:

`git commit -am "Save local changes"
git checkout -B gh-pages
git add -f dist
git commit -am "Rebuild website"
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dist && git push -f origin gh-pages && git checkout -`